# Add event binding to dynamically created components

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm dynamically creating components inside `app.component.ts` using the `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` method, which returns a `ComponentRef` object.

```
let newComponent:ComponentRef<any> = this.filtersSection.createComponent(MyDateRangeComponent);
```

I need to dynamically add an event listener to this component so it listens to the `onDateRangeChange` event and executes the `dateRangeChanged(event)` method defined inside the `app.component.ts` component.

I originally used this component this way inside the app.component.html:

```
<my-daterange (onDateRangeChange)="dateRangeChanged($event)"></my-daterange>
```

I've found that this could be achieved using the `Renderer` class but I couldn't make this working:

```
this.renderer.listen(newComponent, 'click', (event) => {
    // Do something with 'event'
    console.log(event);
});
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `ComponentRef.instance` allows you to access the component instance and with this you can subscribe to the `EventEmitter`:

```
newComponent.instance.onDataRateChange.subscribe(evt => this.result = evt);
```

Comment: how do i add a click listener on the instance ?

Comment: `newComponent.location.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', myClickHandler.bind(this))` or `@Hostlistener('click') myClickHandler(){...}` inside the dynamic component.